# copy the data from one workbook to another workbook using date range

Tags: vba

Hi i have below code which copy the data from one work sheet to another worksheet in the same workbook in between 2 date ranges , but now i am trying to copy data from one workbook to another work book modifying the code but not able to do.

```
Sub DataBasedOnDate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date
Dim MainWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim dtTodayDate As String

StartDate = Sheets("Macro").Range("D6").Value
EndDate = Sheets("Macro").Range("D7").Value

Set MainWorksheet = Worksheets("database1")

MainWorksheet.Activate

Range("F1").CurrentRegion.Sort _
      key1:=Range("F1"), order1:=xlAscending, _
       Header:=xlYes

Range("F1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        ">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy

dtTodayDate = Format(Date, "mmm-dd-yyyy")
On Error GoTo MakeSheet
    Sheets(dtTodayDate).Activate
    Exit Sub
MakeSheet:
    Sheets.Add , Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = dtTodayDate

ActiveSheet.Paste

Selection.Columns.AutoFit

Range("F1").Select

MainWorksheet.Activate

Selection.AutoFilter

Sheets("Macro").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DataBasedOnDate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date
Dim MainWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim dtTodayDate As String

StartDate = Sheets("Macro").Range("D6").Value
EndDate = Sheets("Macro").Range("D7").Value

Set MainWorksheet = Worksheets("database1")

MainWorksheet.Activate

Range("F1").CurrentRegion.Sort _
      key1:=Range("F1"), order1:=xlAscending, _
       Header:=xlYes

Range("F1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        ">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy

dtTodayDate = Format(Date, "mmm-dd-yyyy")

     Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("location.xlsm")

        ActiveSheet.Name = dtTodayDate
        wb.ActiveSheet.Paste 'You can also input range to paste
        Selection.Columns.AutoFit
        Range("F1").Select
```

if you want to return to original workbook, name it as well. You could also use workbook(1).activate. For this example I name it

```
dim wb2 as workbook
    set wb2= workbooks("name of first opened workbook.xlsm")
    wb2.MainWorksheet.Activate

    Selection.AutoFilter

    Sheets("Macro").Activate


End Sub
```

Comment: what i am trying to do is ,i have data in workbook called source.xlsm now i am trying to copy source data from destination.xlsm..i .e  i have macro in destination.xlsm which should copy the data of source to Destinatin.xlsm how do i mention the path?

Comment: So the data is in source.xlsm and you are trying to copy that data to destination.xlsm. To create a path to open up destination.xlsm, instantiate it as a workbook and open it with a file path. 
    1. Dim wb As Workbook
    2. Set wb = Workbooks.Open("location.xlsm")